# merge 2 lists based on first 2 columns

Tags: join, awk

I need to merge 2 lists based on column 1 and 2

**file1:**

```
client1,server1,3000.00
client1,server2,2500.00
client1,server3,1500.00
client2,server1,4500.00
client2,server2,2300.00
client2,server3,1230.00
client3,server1,3400.00
client3,server2,4500.00
client3,server3,1245.00
client4,server1,3400.00
client5,server2,4500.00
client6,server3,1245.00
client7,server1,3400.00
client7,server2,4500.00
client8,server3,1245.00
client8,server1,3400.00
client8,server2,4500.00
client9,server3,1245.00
```

**file2:**

```
client1,server1,windows,250g
client1,server2,linux,450g
client1,server3,linux,400g
client2,server1,windows,250g
client2,server2,linux,450g
client2,server3,linux,400g
client3,server1,windows,250g
client3,server2,linux,450g
client3,server3,linux,400g
```

what I need is to update file2 with the missing values from column 1 an 2 only of file1 and adding comma to keep same number of columns

with this example the output should be like this :

```
client1,server1,windows,250g
client1,server2,linux,450g
client1,server3,linux,400g
client2,server1,windows,250g
client2,server2,linux,450g
client2,server3,linux,400g
client3,server1,windows,250g
client3,server2,linux,450g
client3,server3,linux,400g
client4,server1,,
client5,server2,,
client6,server3,,
client7,server1,,
client7,server2,,
client8,server3,,
client8,server1,,
client8,server2,,
client9,server3,,
```

I have tried with awk and join but I am not able to get the same result

if creating new file is easier then no issue

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk way

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," 'NR!=FNR{NF--;NF+=2}!a[$1 FS $2]++' test2 test
```

or

```
awk -F, 'NR!=FNR{$0=$1 FS $2",,"}!a[$1 FS $2]++' test2 test
```

Shortest

```
awk -F, '{x=$1","$2}NR!=FNR{$0=x",,"}!a[x]++' test2 test
```

Comment: thanks very much Jidder all the 3 are working fine and I like the last one I will mark this answer as accepted many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

give this line a try:

```
awk -F, '{k=$1 FS $2}NR==FNR{a[k]++;print;next}!a[k]{print k",,"}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Hi Kent, this is working perfectly I am not sure what the command is doing but thanks very much

Comment: @joe no problem. I didn't give a test when I wrote it, good to hear that it works there.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `join` command. Problem is `join` can not join on multiple fields, so we need to manipulate the first comma temporarily:

```
join -t , -o 0,2.2,2.3 -a 1 <(sed 's/,/:/' file1) <(sed 's/,/:/' file2) | sed 's/:/,/'
```